# Does the FAA issue multiple physical certificates for different aircraft categories and privileges?

Tags: faa-regulations

If one holds a private pilot certificate in both airplanes and gliders, does the FAA issue two plastic cards that one would have to carry? What if one has commercial privileges in airplanes, but private in gliders?

What about being private in airplane, but sport in powered parachute? Some schools say that if one already has a private in airplane, then powered parachute at sport level would only be a logbook endorsement rather than a new piece of plastic. I was under the impression that logbook endorsements are generally things like the ability to fly a complex airplane, rather than being a sport level in a different category of aircraft.

Comment: I think you have two different questions here, you might want to ask the sport pilot one separately.

Comment: My Remote Pilot certifícate resulted in a different card which didn’t mention my PPL ASEL.

Comment: I have 3 plastic cards, (1) Airline Transport Pilot, (2) Flight Engineer, (3) Ground Instructor, and one old paper card for Flight Instructor that expired in 1990. Each of the cards has various ratings within the type of card.

Answer (score 6):

One certificate would be issued. Your highest rating would be listed on the front and on the back any lower ratings would be outlined.

Before I had passed my rotorcraft ATP my certificate read:

Airline Transport Pilot
 Airplane Single and Multiengine Land

Commerical Privileges
  Rotorcraft-Helicopter

Comment: Only one would be issued.  However, if the pilot has many several type ratings and they all do not fit on the back of one certificate, the FAA will issue a second certificate with hte remainder of the type ratings.

Answer (score 2):

My certificates, ATP MEL, Private SEL (VFR only), and Private Glider are all on one plastic card.  I think Ground Instructor certificates may be a second card, but I don't have any of those so I can't tell you for certain about that.

Comment: Yes, flight instructor certificates are different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate card issued for Flight Instructor and it may have a subset of privileges of those listed on your pilot certificate.  Foe example, you may be an instrument rated pilot but not an instrument flight instructor.

Answer (score 0):

The FAA only issues one "airman certificate" at a time. The highest level and all category/class ratings will be listed first, and then any category/class ratings *not* at the same level will be listed in the Limitations section.

For your first example, you would get a Commercial Pilot Certificate with ASEL and GLI ratings, and then the GLI rating would be limited to Private privileges.

The second example is weird since *every* Private pilot also has Sport privileges, which don't have category/class ratings. As a Sport pilot, you just need a logbook endorsement from *two different* CFIs (rather than a checkride with a DPE) to fly a particular *type* of aircraft.