# How do ratings work with pilot certificates?

Tags: pilot-certification

Just wondering how ratings work with pilot certificates.

Let's say I get both a private pilot certificate and a commercial pilot certificate for airplane / single-engine land.

If I want to add a rotorcraft / helicopter rating onto my commercial pilot certificate for airplane / single-engine land, do I also need to get training to add a rotorcraft / helicopter rating onto my private pilot certificate for airplane / single-engine land also?

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a rating and a certificate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54022/what-is-the-difference-between-a-rating-and-a-certificate)

Comment: Related: [Does the FAA issue multiple physical certificates for different aircraft categories and privileges?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48346/1696)

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to adding a new aircraft category onto your existing Commercial Pilot Certificate in the United States.  Consult the standards of your country's governing body for aeronautics if attempting to do this outside of the USA.

To address the second paragraph, once you hold a Commercial Pilot Certificate for the same category and class of aircraft as your private certificate, you are considered to hold a Commercial Pilot Certificate only.

In regards to the third paragraph, yes additional training will be required to fulfill the requirement of 61.63 (b) for the addition of an aircraft category rating to your CPL.  You will be required to meet the aeronautical experience requirements listed in 61.129 (c) and receive an endorsement in your logbook to take the practical exam in order to add a helicopter category to your CPL.  You will not be required to take the commercial pilot knowledge test again per 61.63 (b).

Comment: Can you take the commercial helicopter checkride without first getting private pilot helicopter privileges? Normally, prerequisites for commercial is that one must already have a private.

Comment: @Pugz - It's not exactly an answer to your question (category, not class) but I took a commercial seaplane (addon to commercial landplane) checkride without ever taking a private ride.

Comment: @SteveV. I have too, but it was only a class add-on, not a category. Hmm.

Comment: @Pugz yes, once you meet the Aeronautical experience requirements for the additional category rating and are endorsed by a CFI to do so, you can just take a commercial checkride and bypass a private checkride altogether.

Comment: @CarloFelicione sweet. That’s what I thought but I haven’t looked into it.